# Passing Query String values from one XAML page to another XAML page - Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml in Silverlight project. I want to pass query string values from Page1.xaml to Page2.xaml on the click event of a button using code behind. Can you please provide me sample code for this ?

1) How to pass query string values from Page1.xaml to Page2.xaml

2) How to retrieve the query string values in Page2.xaml

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) covers these questions:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="home"/>
```

And:

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ProductId"))
{
    productID = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["ProductId"];
}
```

I recommend you use the [UriMapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.urimapper%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), that makes a lot of the handling a lot easier.